# Find sum of multiple sql counts

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, jdeveloper

i'm trying to find the sum of 2 count values stated in the query below. Even though the query is working fine when I'm just finding out the count values, when i try to find the sum of the count values i get an error...Please Help..

```
SELECT COUNT(BUG_ID) BUG_COUNT,
COUNT(STATUS) CLOSED_COUNT,
(BUG_COUNT + CLOSED_COUNT) AS  TOTAL_COUNT
FROM bugzilla_dashboard WHERE CATEGORY='Legacy';
```

The error message I'm getting..

```
ORA-00904: "CLOSED_COUNT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT COUNT(BUG_ID) BUG_COUNT,COUNT(STATUS) CLOSED_COUNT,
      (COUNT(BUG_ID) + COUNT(STATUS)) AS  TOTAL_COUNT
FROM bugzilla_dashboard 
WHERE CATEGORY='Legacy';
```

*Or:*

```
SELECT BUG_COUNT,CLOSED_COUNT,(BUG_COUNT + CLOSED_COUNT) AS  TOTAL_COUNT
FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(BUG_ID) BUG_COUNT,
         COUNT(STATUS) CLOSED_COUNT
  FROM bugzilla_dashboard 
  WHERE CATEGORY='Legacy'
) Tmp
```

Comment: Just to see your answears I would recomend the second approach, as I think it will cost less as it has just two calls to count ... It would be nice to profile the two approaches just to be sure :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(BUG_ID) BUG_COUNT,
COUNT(STATUS) CLOSED_COUNT,
(COUNT(BUG_ID) + COUNT(STATUS)) AS  TOTAL_COUNT
FROM bugzilla_dashboard WHERE CATEGORY='Legacy';
```

obviously...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
   SELECT 
    (COUNT(BUG_ID) +COUNT(STATUS)) 
    AS  
    TOTAL_COUNT 
    FROM 
    bugzilla_dashboard 
    WHERE 
    CATEGORY='Legacy';
```